# Snooping SSL-packets from a WLAN network using Java?

Tags: java

What libraries/jars would you suggest to use?
What theory should I read before doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot immediately snoop SSL-packets from a WLAN network from Java as the network interface configuration code is not present in the standard Java Runtime Library.

Hence you need native libraries, and then you might as well use a native solution.

What do you need this for?

Comment: Getting the packet-snooping part done in java will be a walk in the park compared to actually trying to decode the encrypted packets though.

Comment: @nos he only asked about snooping, not decrypting.  Don't spoil the ending for him (or her)!

Comment: well I need this for University bachlors work, I think I have already found the program(in python) which does bouth snoop+decrypt, well actually this is what I need to program...

Comment: I suggest discussing with your advisor why you even _consider_ doing the data collection in Java. Doesn't hé know your subject well?

Comment: and if my advisor advised to create a program which reads the information being send to the router from lets say a laptop(without any directions what to use or how to do this) ...

Comment: @user605596, consider using a native program that can dump network traffic and then learn how to communicate with it using the tools you are familiar with.